# Bind label Content to string property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind the content of a label to a local property called "Status".

Codesnipped:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var logFilePath = GetPathToAppDirPlusLocalPath("LogFiles/MainLog.txt");
        MainLog = new Log(@logFilePath);
        MainLog.Add("MainWindow initialized");
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private string _Status = null;
    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            return _Status;
        }
        set
        {
            _Status = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");  //Call the method to set off the PropertyChanged event.
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Border x:Name="brd_Status" Grid.Row="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Background="Black" DataContext="Status">
        <Label x:Name="lbl_Status" Content="{Binding Path=Status,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Grid.Row="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="10"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            FontSize="16" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Asenine">
        </Label>
    </Border>
```

I also tried `Content = {Binding Status...}` but makes no difference.

The label is just "null", while the property "Status" is "abcd1234...".

I debugged it and but, I am not sure where to search for a failure...

Comment: Look for `System.Data` exceptions. Also setting your `UpdateSourceTrigger` on a `Label` element makes no sense. Labels will *never* update their source

Comment: Can you show the class def? Do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Do you mean "public partial class MainWindow : Window"? Do I need to creat a "public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged" one? And what do I need to do then...?

Comment: You need to note that you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` yes, just add it to the inheritance list.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET how? and then what? do I need to do something else? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `MainWindow` is not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` so even though you have and are raising the appropriate event, the runtime hasn't registered for it.

Change your class definition to:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

**Also consider using a proper view model (look up MVVM)**, puting INPC on a view object is very bad design, and note that an `UpdateSourceTrigger` on a `Label` is useless as `Label` controls cannot be changed in the UI.

Comment: cant use "public class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged", compiler says i need "public partical class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged" and even then it´s still not working... the event handler are fine as they are? Becouse where to I use the "INotifyPropertyChanged"?

Comment: @Sinmson The rest looks right. You should be able to debug it from there.

Comment: when the compiler jumps into the "NotifyPropertyChanged" method, the "PropertyChanged "(PropertyChangedEventHandler) is null, so the handler doesnt call himself, but why is the "PropertyChanged" null and how do I change it?

Comment: @Sinmson It won't be null if you correctly implemented the interface and have set the DataContext.

Comment: i added "INotifyPropertyChanged" and the DataContext was already set in the constructor, i did everything....that are those moments i hate programming lel ._. ps: At the end it will be my fault for sure

Comment: @Sinmson I would check for `System.Data` exceptions and make sure you don't have any typos (for example, that you don't have *two* events after implementing the interface due to a misspelling)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET so afraid someone else saw this answer and learnt putting INotifyPropertyChanged in their window class ... lol